# Can I get the complete IP prefix lists?

Tags: ipv4, bgp, internet

People talked about we have around >600k IP prefix blocks in use today. Out of curiosity, is there a place finding all the in-use IP prefix?

How to make sure such list up to date?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

RIPE NCC has a set of route collectors and offers their routing tables for download: https://www.ripe.net/analyse/internet-measurements/routing-information-service-ris/ris-raw-data. They have historical data going back to at least 1999.

Answer (score 2):

Today, February 24 2017, I have one ISP that advertises me 626063 routes and another one 625418.

(the difference being due to different summarization between each ISP)

Many providers provide [BGP looking glasses](https://www.google.be/search?q=bgp+looking+glass) which allow you to query BGP tables in real time. Not sure if any allow you to dump an entire table.